# String replace not working

Tags: c#

```
public static string ChangeUriToHttps(HttpRequest request)
{
    string uri = request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

    if (!IsRequestSecure(request))
        uri.Replace("http", "https");

    return uri;
}
```

If I send in a request that has a uri like this:

```
http://localhost/AppName/somepage.aspx
```

it doesn't replace the http with https.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

common mistake.  Strings are immutable.  This means the original object can't be modified.

```
 public static string ChangeUriToHttps(HttpRequest request)
 {
      string uri = request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

      if (!IsRequestSecure(request))
          uri = uri.Replace("http", "https");

      return uri;
 }
```