# string.Replace (or other string modification) not working

Tags: c#

For the following code, I can't get the `string.Replace` to work:

```
someTestString.Replace(someID.ToString(), sessionID);
```

when I debug and check parameters they have values I expect - i.e. `someID.ToString()` got "1087163075", and `sessionID` has "108716308" and `someTestString` contains "1087163075".

**I have no idea why this would not work change `someTestString`**

Complete sample:

```
string someTestString = 
      "<a href='myfoldert/108716305-1.jpg' target='_blank'>108716305-1.jpg</a>"
someTestString.Replace("108716305", "NewId42");
```

the result (in `someTestString`) should be this:

```
"<a href='myfoldert/NewId42-1.jpg' target='_blank'>NewId42-1.jpg</a>"
```

but it doesn't change.  The string for `someTestString` remains unchanged after hitting my code.

Comment: Classic .net coding mistake. I guess everyone already ran into it once or twice in a hurry :-)))

Comment: So common that CoffeeAddict made the same mistake after a month :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558024/string-replace-not-working

Comment: Note that the exact same issue exists for every operation on type `System.String` which you would expect to change the string - they don't change the string - they return a new string with the change.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Strings are immutable.  The result of `string.Replace` is a new string with the replaced value.

You can either store result in new variable:

```
var newString = someTestString.Replace(someID.ToString(), sessionID);
```

or just reassign to original variable if you just want observe "string updated" behavior:

```
someTestString = someTestString.Replace(someID.ToString(), sessionID);
```

Note that this applies to all other `string` functions like `Remove`, `Insert`, trim and substring variants - all of them return new string as original string can't be modified.

Comment: so looks like you can't just do this and set it to itself either: someTestString = someTestString.Replace(someID.ToString(), sessionID);

Comment: well, I guess I need to start looking into regex more...as painful as it is for a newbie who has not touched much of it....because this is just gay and regex is the best next choice.

Comment: Are you sure your arguments are correct?  You said that someID is 108716307, yet your someTestString has the value 108716305... so the last digit is different, so it wouldn't match.

Comment: It's bad naming.  The trouble is, any other name would be longer and awkward.  (GetWithReplacement?  GetAfterReplacing?  ReplaceAndReturn?)

Comment: "so looks like you can't just do this and set it to itself either" - yes, you can.

Answer (score 2):

```
someTestString = someTestString.Replace(someID.ToString(), sessionID);
```

that should work for you

Answer (score 1):

strings are immutable, the replace will return a new string so you need something like

```
string newstring = someTestString.Replace(someID.ToString(), sessionID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired effect by using

```
someTestString = someTestString.Replace(someID.ToString(), sessionID);
```

As womp said, strings are immutable, which means their values cannot be changed without changing the entire object.