# Replace part of a filename in C#

Tags: string, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a folder with `.pdf` files. In the names of most files I want to replace specific string with another string.

Here's what I've written.

```
  private void btnGetFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = tbGetFIles.Text;
        List<string> FileNames = new List<string>();

        DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

        foreach (FileInfo File in DirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            FileNames.Add(File.Name);       
        }

        lbFileNames.DataSource = FileNames;
    }
```

Here I extract all file names in List Box.

```
    private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strReplace = tbReplace.Text; // The existing string
        string strWith = tbWith.Text; // The new string

        string dir = tbGetFIles.Text;
        DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        FileInfo[] names = DirInfo.GetFiles();


        foreach (FileInfo f in names)
        {
            if(f.Name.Contains(strReplace))
            {
                f.Name.Replace(strReplace, strWith);
            }

        }
```

And here I want to do the replacing, but something is going wrong. What?

Comment: "but something gones wrong. What?" You're supposed to tell us what went wrong (what problem you're having), and we can help you figure out how to fix it. You haven't done so. Please edit your question so that there actually **is** a question that can be answered. Thanks. :)

Comment: [Replace doesn't replace. Replace returns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-not-working).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the name of the file on disk.  If so then you need to use the `File.Move` API vs. changing the actual string which is the file name.

One other mistake you are making is the `Replace` call itself.  A `string` in .Net is immutable and hence all of the mutating APIs like `Replace` return a new `string` vs. changing the old one in place.  To see the change you need to assign the new value back to a variable

```
string newName = f.Name.Replace(strReplace, strWith);
File.Move(f.Name, newName);
```

Answer (score 2):

f.Name is a read-only property. f.Name.Replace(..) simply returns a new string with the filename you want, but never actually changes the file.
I suggest something along the following, though I haven't tested it:

```
File.Move(f.Name, f.Name.Replace(strReplace, strWith));
```

Comment: It works: 

File.Move(dir + @"\" + f.Name, dir + @"\" + f.Name.Replace(strReplace, strWith));

Comment: good catch.  Even better would probably be to use Path.Combine

Answer (score 1):

Replace return another string, it doesn't change the original string.
So you need to write

```
string newName = f.Name.Replace(strReplace, strWith);
```

of course this doesn't change the name of the file on disk.
If that was your intention then you should look at

```
File.Move(f.Name, newName);
```

also keep in mind that File.Move will fail with an exception if the destination file exists.

[See here for an example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-move)

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, seems like you're not reassigning the replaced string to your f.Name variable. Try this:

```
string NewFileName = f.Name.Replace(strReplace, strWith);
File.Copy(f.Name, NewFileName);
File.Delete(f.Name);
```

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing it out. I have modified my reply.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `string.Replace` this doesn't alter your existing string. Instead it is returning a new string.

You need to change your code to something like this:

```
if(f.Name.Contains(strReplace)) 
{ 
    string newFileName = f.Name.Replace(strReplace, strWith); 
    //and work here with your new string
}
```