# Date Taken of an Image C#

Tags: c#, rename

I need to rename my Image (.jpg) and  the new name needs to include the date taken. I can get the date taken of the image but can not include it into new File name.

```
Image im = new Bitmap("FileName.....");
PropertyItem pi = im.GetPropertyItem(0x132);
dateTaken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pi.Value);
dateTaken = dateTaken.Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "");
string newName = dateTaken +".jpg" ;
MessageBox.Show(newName.ToString());
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific what the problem is? Show us the code that does not work.

Comment: In the code i have append ".jpg" (or any string) , but when show it, nothing happends

Comment: Try outputting the value of `dateTaken`. Does it contain the right value?

Comment: For future reference, you have to be able to clearly explain the problem you're having if you're expecting help. People provided multiple solutions because we had no idea what you were trying to do (I still don't know if you're trying to change a filename on disk or in a message box). To come back later and just say "problem is fixed. thanks a lot." is disrespectful to time spent by people trying to help you and makes it less likely you'll get good help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So is the problem that you can't get the date into the string you're trying to show in the message box or are you trying to change the filename of the image? If you want to change the image filename, you have to modify the file itself. Look at [Replace part of a filename in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487696/replace-part-of-a-filename-in-c-sharp)

Comment: i want to replace the filename of the image in the form DateTaken.jpg

Comment: Then we'd need more information on what error you're getting. I'm assuming that in your code dateTaken is typed as a string or var or something?

Comment: Image im = new Bitmap("FileName.....");
PropertyItem pi = im.GetPropertyItem(0x132);
string dateTaken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pi.Value);
dateTaken = dateTaken.Replace(":", "_").Replace(" ", "_");
string newName = dateTaken + ".jpg";
MessageBox.Show(newName);

Comment: I have already copied this code into your question, it is there for all to see. You do not need to post it again under every comment. If you want to update it, please edit your question. Have you checked whether `dateTaken` contains a meaningful value?

Comment: I think people here would be happy to help you if we had more information on your problem instead of just getting the code pasted again. Check the value of dateTaken in the debugger as Chris suggested and if you still have problems, give this an exception or stack trace or something.

Comment: yes, i did. i have no problem with getting the Date taken. But i can not use it to creating new string for new name

Comment: So if dateTaken outputs the right value, and newName outputs the value of dateTaken with ".jpg" o the end, then it should display fine in the MessageBox. What do you see when the message box appears?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using this code? Because this string concatenation should work fine. BTW, you don't need to call toString() on string objects.

Comment: problem has been fixed. Thanks a lot

Comment: @nguyenviethai Will you please let as know how you fixed it, e.g. by writing an answer to your question?

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to rename your jpeg file, you could try the code below.

This code will extract the date from an image (requires the image's full file path), convert it to a different format and then use it as a new file name. The code to rename the file is commented out, so that you can see the result in the console before trying it on your local machine.

**Sample Code. Please use your own fully qualified file path**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Globalization;

// This is just an example directory, please use your fully qualified file path
string oldFilePath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\image.JPG";
// Get the path of the file, and append a trailing backslash
string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(oldFilePath) + @"\";

// Get the date property from the image
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(oldFilePath);
PropertyItem test = image.GetPropertyItem(0x132);

// Extract the date property as a string
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding a = new ASCIIEncoding();
string date = a.GetString(test.Value, 0, test.Len - 1);

// Create a DateTime object with our extracted date so that we can format it how we wish
System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime dateCreated = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy:MM:d H:m:s", provider);

// Create our own file friendly format of daydayMonthMonthYearYearYearYear
string fileName = dateCreated.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

// Create the new file path
string newPath = directory + fileName + ".JPG";

// Use this method to rename the file
//System.IO.File.Move(oldFilePath, newPath);

Console.WriteLine(newPath);
```