# How do you replace a character in a string with a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the example below I have a string with pipes `|` separating each segment in the string (ie:0123456789). What I am trying to do is replace the pipe character with a string as shown in the example below. How do I accomplish that?

From what I understand the `.Replace` can only support `(char,char)` or `(string, string)`.

Example code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String val1 = "0123456789|0123456789|0123456789|0123456789|0123456789";
            val1.Replace('|'.ToString(), "*val1TEST*");
            String val2 = "0123456789|0123456789|0123456789|0123456789|0123456789";
            val2.Replace("|", "**val2Test**");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}","val1: ",val1));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}", "val2: ", val2));
        }
    }
}
```

Output From Console

```
val1: 0123456789|0123456789|0123456789|0123456789|0123456789

val2: 0123456789|0123456789|0123456789|0123456789|0123456789
```

Comment: assign it back `val1 = val1.Replace('|'.ToString(), "*val1TEST*");` strings are immutable.

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-not-working

Comment: As Habib correctly said, strings are immutable. This means you cannot change the object it self. but you can change the value it references. val1 = val1.Replace(.....), will change the value val1 references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the definition for [`.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it returns a string - so you need to set it to a variable like so:

```
val1 = val1.Replace('|'.ToString(), "*val1TEST*");
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this post, I forgot to set it to a variable. I'm going to accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that `Replace()` returns a string. It doesn't modify the existing string. You need to set the strings to the return value:

```
str = str.Replace(...);
```

Furthermore, a string with one character is the same as a single character, which is why there is no `Replace(char, string)`.