# How to trim a string?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Value of rate.TierId is '  Zone1_ResidentialSales_LoansEscrowServices'. i have two spaces in start of string.I want to remove those spaces.
I used below code, but ot's not working'

```
rate.TierId.ToString().Trim()
```

please sugeest me some other way

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: @SLaks: ok, now where's the canonical question for this one (no, I don't have time to create one today)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [string.Replace not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-not-working)

Comment: @JohnSaunders I think "string.Replace not working" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-not-working) is good enough (also not exactly canonical for `.Trim`...)

Comment: Thanks. That's good enough. I think I'll change the title of the dupe to add "(or other string modification)"

Answer (score 3):

```
string trimmedString = rate.TierId.ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using trim() you could try using string.replace(oldValue, newValue).

When using the replace method you need to specify the value equating to itself e.g.

```
yourString = yourString.replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: This will remove all spaces from a string, not just the ones from the beginning or end.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, use a new string variable.

`string trimmedRate = rate.TierId.ToString().Trim();`