# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Zon7' to data type int

Tags: linq, c#-6.0, entity-framework-core-2.1

I'm getting this error :

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Zon7' to data
>   type int.

```
establishments = GetEstablishments(waters.Select(t => ReplaceZonToEmptyString(t.IdGeographie)));

public static int ReplaceZonToEmptyString(string zoneId)
{
     zoneId.Replace("Zon", string.Empty);
     var sbInput = zoneId.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
     return Convert.ToInt32(sbInput.ToString());
 }

 public static IQueryable<Etablissement> GetEstablishments(IQueryable<int> ids)       
 {
   return from zone in entities.Zones
          where ids.Contains(zone.IdZone)
          select zone.IdBatimentNavigation.IdEtablissementNavigation;

 }

var result = establishments.ToList();
```

in database i have a column of type varchar the column name is '**IdGeographie**' with values that start with 'Zon', something like this "ZonXXXX"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string.Replace (or other string modification) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working)

Comment: Instead of trying to convert a StringBuilder (in a rather weird way) to an int, see the above duplicate.

Comment: I edited my code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a `VARCHAR` column with values of type `int`. One of these values will have to change and since it con not be the SQL column, it has to be the compare value:

```
public static string ReplaceZonToEmptyString(string zoneId)
{
    var sbInput = new StringBuilder(zoneId);
    sbInput.Replace("Zon", string.Empty);
    sbInput.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    return sbInput.ToString();
}

public static IQueryable<Etablissement> GetEstablishments(IQueryable<string> ids)       
{
    return from zone in entities.Zones
        where ids.Contains(zone.IdZone)
        select zone.IdBatimentNavigation.IdEtablissementNavigation;
}
```

If the signature of the methods can't change, you have to do the conversion within `GetEstablishments`:

```
public static IQueryable<Etablissement> GetEstablishments(IQueryable<int> ids)       
{
    var textIds = ids.Select(id => id.ToString());
    return from zone in entities.Zones
        where textIds.Contains(zone.IdZone)
        select zone.IdBatimentNavigation.IdEtablissementNavigation;
}
```

Note that in `waters.Select(t => ReplaceZonToEmptyString(t.IdGeographie))`, the value `waters` must be a materialized list of values (i.e. not another EF query), since your replace operation can not work within Entity Framework (in either of the options).

Comment: i can't change the signature of this methode, it's used everywhere and contain other code...

Comment: @OmarAMEZOUG: The signature of which method?

Comment: waters is an other EF query and i can't change this method!, maybe i have to add an other column of type int to the table!

Comment: @OmarAMEZOUG Can you not materialize the IDs extracted from `waters` and then pass the IDs to `GetEstablishments` (using `AsQueryable`).

Comment: @OmarAMEZOUG: You can under no circumstances call `ReplaceZonToEmptyString` on a non-materialized LINQ query. EF will not be able to handle it.

Comment: my waters query is not materialize,  var waters = (from water in entities.Eaux select water);

Comment: You can `waters.Select(t => ReplaceZonToEmptyString(t.IdGeographie)).ToArray()` to materialize the IDs which will create an `int[]`

Comment: @vc74 ids are type of IQueryable<int> and table of water are very huge, i want to avoid getting data then send again to get result from DB

Comment: @OmarAMEZOUG But as Sefe commented, EF will not be able to convert the logic in `ReplaceZonToEmptyString` into SQL

Answer (score 0):

What do you think the following code will do:

```
string original = "Hello World!";
string changed = original.Recplace("o", "xx");
```

`original` won't be changed, `changed` will equal "Hellxx, Wxxrld".

So you should change your ReplaceZonToEmptyString:

```
public static int ExtractZoneNr(string zoneId)
{
    string idWithoutZon = zoneId.Replace("Zon", string.Empty);
    string sbInput = idWithoutZon.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
    return Int32.Parse(sbInput);
}
```

Alas this will only work on IEnumerable, not on IQueryable

**A better solution:**

This solution only works if `IdGeographie` is the three letters "Zon" followed by the string representation of the `IdZone` and nothing else. So no spaces, no leading zeroes etc: "Zon4" and not "Zon004", nor "Zon  4"

You have two `IQueryables` one for waters and one for zones:

```
IQuerybale<Water> waters = ...            // probably entities.Waters
IQueryable<Zone> zones = entities.Zones
```

Every `Zone` contains an int property `IdZone`, and a property `.IdBatimentNavigation.IdEtablissementNavigation`, which seems to be of type `Etablissement`

Furhermore every `Water` has a string property `GeographieId` in the format "ZonX" where X is an integer number.

Now you want to query the `IdBatimentNavigation.IdEtablissementNavigation` of all `Zones` with an `IdZone` that equals the X part of one or more of the `Waters`

For example: if you have the following `Waters`

```
[0] GeographieId = "Zon10"
[1] GeographieId = "Zon42"
[2] GeographieId = "Zon7"
```

And you have `Zones` with `IdZone`: 4, 42, 30, 7, 22.

Then as a result you want the `IdBatimentNavigation.IdEtablissementNavigation` of the `Zones` with `IdZone`: 42 any 7 (in any order)

Why not join waters and zones?

```
var result = zones.
    .Select(zone => new
    {
        GeographieId = "Zon" + zone.IdZone.ToString(),
        Etablissement = zoneIdBatimentNavigation.IdEtablissementNavigation,
    })
    .Join(waters,                            // join with waters
       zone => zone.GeographieId,            // from zone take the GeoGraphieId
       water => water,                       // from waters take idGeographie
       (zone, water) => zone.Etablissement); // when thay match return
```

A better solution would be to try to remove the "Zon" part from IdGeographie, and Parse the remaining XXXX to an int. Alas there is no function that can perform the parsing AsQueryable.