# c# Replace string in a property of a class using linq not working

Tags: c#, linq, replace

I am trying to find a specific string in a property of a class and replace it with another string if found. I tried various methods using Linq but I am not able to replace it. In debug mode, when I monitor the object again, the replace command hasn't worked. Please help. Including a sample example below.

```
class Tryreplace
{
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
}

List<Tryreplace> tryreplaces = new List<Tryreplace>();

Tryreplace tryreplace = new Tryreplace { ClubName = "Manchester United FC" };

Tryreplace tryreplace2 = new Tryreplace { ClubName = "Arsenal FC" };

tryreplaces.Add(tryreplace);

tryreplaces.Add(tryreplace2);
```

Tried 2 ways below, both didn't work...

```
tryreplaces.ForEach(x => x.ClubName.Replace("Manchester", "Newcastle"));



List<Tryreplace> tryreplaces2 = tryreplaces.Select(x => { x.ClubName.Replace("Manchester", "Newcastle"); return x; }).ToList();
```

After both, I only see Manchester and not Newcastle.

I would like to see replaced string Newcastle in the objects and not Manchester. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string.Replace (or other string modification) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have an look at the official Documentation from the `String.Replace()` Method:

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in
>   the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

So you will need to set the property as shown in the Example:

```
tryreplaces.ForEach(x => x.ClubName = x.ClubName.Replace("Manchester", "Newcastle"))
```

[String.Replace() Docs from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: Nice catch ..:)

Answer (score 4):

in C# (or most language) `string` are immutable, mean whenever you are making change to it, it will create another instance of string, but it will not change self variable itself.

Or simply if you want to replace part of the string you need to assign make to original variable.

```
string name = "Amyn";
name.Replace("A", "@");
Console.WriteLine(name);       // it will be still Amyn
name = name.Replace("A", "@");  // its right way 
Console.WriteLine(name);       // it will display "@myn"
```

so in your code also you need to assign the variable back.

```
tryreplaces.ForEach(x => x.ClubName = x.ClubName.Replace("Manchester", "Newcastle"))
```