# C#: Adding invisible character to a string

Tags: c#

I have a Windows form that has a drop down of value "Main Area". I take this value and embed it into a string.

But the third party application that we use does not like spaces in the string. Is there a way that I can add an invisible character using C# so that it doesn't seem like an empty space?

I tried `string.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");`, `string.replace(" ", "%20")` etc..etc.. but doesn't work.

Comment: How do you know the other program will like the HTML or URL encoding, and did you [use `Replace` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1948984/11683)?

Comment: We do not know what the third party application is, so we cannot tell you what you should put there to make it look like a space.

Comment: You could try the `no-break space` - `string.Replace(" ", "\u00A0");`

Comment: You could try the non-breaking space character.  `.Replace(" ", "\u00A0")`

Comment: you are doing mystring = mystring.replace(..) .. arent you?

Comment: Thank you guys, yes I tried the UTF-8 coding as well. To be honest we dont know how the third party reads the string, but to avoid being charged for changes I am trying to fix it on my end. Yes, using the .replace function correctly.