# Text replace in C# string

Tags: c#, string, windows, forms, textbox

when replacing a text in a textbox it does not work for me, I attach the code that I use. I am working on windows form with c #

```
string struser = "";
struser = txtusu.Text;
struser.ToUpper();
struser.Replace("=", "0");
struser.Replace(";", ":");
struser.Replace("Ñ", ":");
struser.Replace("ñ", ":");
struser.Replace("u", "U");
struser.Replace("U:", "");
struser.Trim();
```

It should be noted that I have the code in a keypress event.

Comment: If you look at the [string.Replace documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace), it says clearly that it returns a new string with the text replaced. It doesn't modify the current string variable. Therefore you'd have to do something like `struser = struser.Replace("=", "0");`

Comment: string is immutable.  You have to asign all of those calls to something.

Comment: FYI you can just chain all of those calls together `txtusu.Text = txtusu.Text.ToUpper().Replace(.....).Trim();`

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working. I think that it is related to your problem.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev Thanks, I've gone ahead and closed this question as a duplicate of that one. Feel free to flag as a duplicate next time - makes the process a bit easier.

Comment: @mason I don't have flag duplicate. May be I don't have enough reputation for it.

Comment: What does the [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1) (and [ToUpper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.toupper?view=netcore-3.1) and [Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netcore-3.1)) documentation tell you about those methods?

Comment: Also, that first assignment can be removed since the string just gets reassigned on the next line.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev Ah - perhaps they removed the ability to flag for it. Anyways at 3K reputation you can cast close votes, so good luck getting there!

Comment: @mason, yo, duplicate flag is history

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable in C# so you have to assign the results of methods that update them back to the source variable/property.  Also you can just chain method calls to avoid having a bunch of assignments.

```
txtusu.Text = txtusu.Text
    .ToUpper()
    .Replace("=", "0")
    .Replace(";", ":")
    .Replace("Ñ", ":")
    .Replace("ñ", ":")
    .Replace("u", "U")
    .Replace("U:", "")
    .Trim();
```