# Why does my ordered list not stay ordered?

Tags: c#, linq, itext

I have a class:

```
public class PairODocs
{
    public string Whirred;
    public int Doc1Count = 0;
    public double Doc1Prcntg = 0.0;
    public int Doc2Count = 0;
    public double Doc2Prcntg = 0.0;
}
```

...and a list of it:

```
List<PairODocs> lstPairODocs;
```

When I try to order it by Doc1Prcntg, like so:

```
lstPairODocs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Doc1Prcntg);
```

...it apparently does not do so. Thereafter using the loop code below to add it to a PDF document (iText 7):

```
foreach (PairODocs pod in lstPairODocs)
{
    table.AddCell(pod.Whirred);
    table.AddCell(pod.Doc1Count.ToString());
    table.AddCell(pod.Doc1Prcntg.ToString());
    table.AddCell(pod.Doc2Count.ToString());
    table.AddCell(pod.Doc2Prcntg.ToString());
}
```

...here is the data produced:

[image]

(still in alphabetical order, rather than by Doc1Prcntg descending).

I also tried this:

```
// after the call to lstPairODocs.OrderByDescending():
List<PairODocs> lstPairODocs2 = lstPairODocs;
```

...and this:

```
List<PairODocs> lstPairODocs2 = new List<PairODocs>(lstPairODocs);
```

...and then replacing lstPairODocs with lstPairODocs2 in the loop:

```
foreach (PairODocs pod in lstPairODocs2)
```

...but that made no difference.

Comment: It returns a new value. Doesn’t operate in place. [Documentation with examples is available online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I had this problem and what worked was creating the list, and creating a new variable of that list like so, `var newList = 1stPairODocs2.OrderByDescending(e => e.whatever);` It is not ideal but thats how I got it to work

Comment: It is pretty well known that absolutely nothing works in C# - you can see it yourself https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+OrderByDescending+does+not+work ... (even such simple operation like [String.Replace does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working)... what you expect from sorting) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq order by does not mutate the collection, it returns a new collection which is ordered. Just catch it:

```
YourList = YourList.OrderByDescending..
```

Or iterate through it :

```
foreach(PairODocs p in YourList.OrderByDescending..)
```

Comment: The second option seemed the least intrusive, and works like a champ. Thanks!