# c# cannot set a variable from a simple array

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I amm reading a text file using c#.

```
string[] allRigas;    
allRigas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\testFolder\2021.1.26.5.47.37-Events.txt");
```

When I do the for loop I cant read value of any row.

```
for (int i = 0; i < allRigas.Length; i++)
{ 
    string theRiga = allRigas[i].Trim(); 
}
```

The variable (thsRiga) empty, but the array is full like this
[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0ckb.png)

Can someone help me?

EDIT 1:
Sorry for incomplete information, following is a detail code.

```
public string[] GetRigasTxt(DateTime dataFile)
        {
            // -- data inserita
            string dataFormatted = dataFile.ToString();

            // -- prendi tutti i nomi dei file all interno per poi confrontare la data e selezionare quello corretto
            List<string> listBox = new List<string>();
            var folder = @"C:\testFolder";
            var txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
            listBox.AddRange(txtFiles);

            // -- prendi tutti i dati all interno del file selezionato
            string[] allRigas;
            allRigas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\testFolder\2021.1.26.5.47.37-Events.txt");



            // -- calcolo tempo totale per quel file
            string[] bothVal = { };
            int tempo1 = 0;
            int tempo2 = 0;

            try 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < allRigas.Length; i++)
                {

                    string theRiga = allRigas[i].Trim();

                    theRiga.Replace("\t", "");
                    theRiga.Replace(" ", "");

                    int test = theRiga.Length;

                    if (theRiga.Length == 162)
                    {
                        if (theRiga.Substring(49, 1) == "1")
                        {
                            tempo1 += Convert.ToInt32(theRiga.Substring(21, 3));
                        }
                        else if (theRiga.Substring(49, 1) == "2")
                        {
                            tempo2 += Convert.ToInt32(theRiga.Substring(21, 3));
                        }
                    }
                    else if (theRiga.Length == 160)
                    {
                        if (theRiga.Substring(47, 1) == "1")
                        {
                            tempo1 += Convert.ToInt32(theRiga.Substring(21, 3));
                        }
                        else if (theRiga.Substring(47, 1) == "2")
                        {
                            tempo2 += Convert.ToInt32(theRiga.Substring(21, 3));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(GlobalVariables.errorFolderLocation + "GetRigasTxtJSON.txt", e.ToString());
            }

            bothVal[0] = tempo1.ToString();
            bothVal[1] = tempo2.ToString();

            return bothVal;
            
        }
```

I cannot find value in variable theRiga on debugging, so the return value is 0 and 0.

EDIT 2:
my txt file contains many rows like this:

> 26.01.2021    08.42.00    655                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 1
> 26.01.2021  08.42.41    971                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 2
> 26.01.2021  08.44.41    018                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 1
> 26.01.2021  08.45.19    293                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 1
> 26.01.2021  08.46.48    286                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 2
> 26.01.2021  08.47.21    011                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 2
> 26.01.2021  08.48.39    842                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 1
> 26.01.2021  08.49.18    117                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 1
> 26.01.2021  08.50.21    406                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 2
> 26.01.2021  08.50.54    141                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 2
> 26.01.2021  08.53.28    783                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 1
> 26.01.2021  08.54.06    979                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 1
> 26.01.2021  08.54.09    719                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 2
> 26.01.2021  08.54.42    444                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 2
> 26.01.2021  08.56.15    257                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 1
> 26.01.2021  08.56.53    532                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 1
> 26.01.2021  08.57.39    969                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 2
> 26.01.2021  08.58.12    693                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 2
> 26.01.2021  09.00.03    169                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 1
> 26.01.2021  09.00.41    435                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 1
> 26.01.2021  09.01.57    986                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 2
> 26.01.2021  09.02.30    710                 AVE084                  Cycle Start Table 2
> 26.01.2021  09.04.50    120                 AVE084                  Cycle End Table 1

Comment: [ask], [Mre] may be use full here. The code should work. We don't have enought information to reproduce the issue. My bet is a variable name/scope issue `thisRiga` you talked about does not exist in the code it's `theRiga`.

Comment: what is `thisRiga`, you just declared `theRiga` and i can't see any faulty code here. it should work as expected

Comment: Just print the variable you will see that it work just fine `Console.WriteLine(theRiga);`. Note that it should be between the curly brace of the for loop. The local variable `string theRiga` will not be accessible after.

Comment: `theRiga.Replace("\t", "");` Hint - you need to _assign_ that to something.

Comment: Here is the dupe target : [string.Replace (or other string modification) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/)

Comment: @user222137, you first two block of code is fine. It works.

Comment: i have fixed the replace, but i havent the value at the start of the loop: string theRiga = allRigas[i].Trim(); this cannot read the value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string.Replace (or other string modification) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working)

Comment: @user222137, Can you post some values in array "allRigas" here? You can update the question.

Comment: my problem is theRiga hasn't a value, (my replace was wrong and its ok now)

Comment: @NCCSBIM071 i posted the images that show dats

Comment: @user222137, if variable theRiga is empty, then can you post some rows in file "2021.1.26.5.47.37-Events.txt" here?

Comment: When you remove spaces and tabs, your length-check and substring-positions may fail, as you have just changed the string length. A .Trim() will also remove leading whitespace, again shifting the contents

Comment: Suggestion: instead of a `.Length` check, check whether the string [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) "Cycle Start" or "Cycle End"

Comment: There is no enough info, If you can give me more information about array data. thanks

Comment: i posted the edit with the contains of txt file

Comment: theRiga hasnt a value, so replace, if, length are usless beacause my string is always empty

Comment: I suspect you are looking at the wrong file.

Comment: If i pass the array at jquery it works i can see all my datas, when i go in for loop a cant assign a row at a variable

Comment: Are you sure the lines a 160/162 char length? https://dotnetfiddle.net/k0NbLg. And you don't have any exception doing `string[] bothVal = { };  bothVal[0] = tempo1.ToString();`?

Comment: With the correct index for parsing on this example ? it just works. https://dotnetfiddle.net/8RH30w . You should not add try catch, and code without them. Let the error explode in your face so you will see them. I just added proper initialisation of your array. Im still puzzle by where is your break point when you observe theriga with no values.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you are trying to achieve with this code but I made additional investigation after you posted file content and discovered you have problem a problem where you are checking length of the row. See code below the commented code in following code snippet. With this code snippet, at least `bothVal[0]` and `bothVal[1]` is not 0. Hope it is helpful.

```
public string[] GetRigasTxt(DateTime dataFile)
{
    // -- data inserita
    string dataFormatted = dataFile.ToString();

    // -- prendi tutti i nomi dei file all interno per poi confrontare la data e selezionare quello corretto
    List<string> listBox = new List<string>();
    var folder = @"C:\testFolder";
    var txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
    listBox.AddRange(txtFiles);

    // -- prendi tutti i dati all interno del file selezionato
    string[] allRigas;
    allRigas = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\testFolder\2021.1.26.5.47.37-Events.txt");



    // -- calcolo tempo totale per quel file
    //string[] bothVal = { };
    int tempo1 = 0;
    int tempo2 = 0;

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allRigas.Length; i++)
        {

            string theRiga = allRigas[i].Trim();

            theRiga.Replace("\t", "");
            theRiga.Replace(" ", "");

            int test = theRiga.Length;

            //if (theRiga.Length == 162)
            if (theRiga.Length == 50)
            {
                if (theRiga.Substring(49, 1) == "1")
                {
                    tempo1 += Convert.ToInt32(theRiga.Substring(21, 3));
                }
                else if (theRiga.Substring(49, 1) == "2")
                {
                    tempo2 += Convert.ToInt32(theRiga.Substring(21, 3));
                }
            }
            //else if (theRiga.Length == 160)
            else if (theRiga.Length == 48)
            {
                if (theRiga.Substring(47, 1) == "1")
                {
                    tempo1 += Convert.ToInt32(theRiga.Substring(21, 3));
                }
                else if (theRiga.Substring(47, 1) == "2")
                {
                    tempo2 += Convert.ToInt32(theRiga.Substring(21, 3));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(GlobalVariables.errorFolderLocation + "GetRigasTxtJSON.txt", e.ToString());
    }

    //bothVal[0] = tempo1.ToString();
    //bothVal[1] = tempo2.ToString();    
    string[] bothVal = { tempo1.ToString(), tempo2.ToString() };

    return bothVal;

}
```

Comment: I doubt `theRiga.Replace("\t", "");` should be there.