# When I use split.string and Convert.ToInt32 the value changes, why?

Tags: c#

For example,

```
string a = "4,3,2";
a.Split(',');
int one = Convert.ToInt32(a[0]);
int two = Convert.ToInt32(a[2]);
```

If I were to Console.WriteLine(a[0]); it will give me 4, and Console.WriteLine(a[2]) will give me 2. However, Console.WriteLine(one) and Console.WriteLine(two) gives me 52 and 50 respectively. Why is this so?

Comment: You're not using the result of `a.Split(',')` -- you're throwing it away, and then looking at the characters at indexes 0 and 2, which are `4` and `3`. `Convert.ToInt32(char)` gives you the ASCII value of the character: it doesn't parse it as an integer. You probably want `var split = a.Split(','); int one = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);`, etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string.Replace (or other string modification) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character `'4'` is unicode codepoint 52 and character `'3'` unicode codepoint 51. You're converting characters instead of strings. The problem is that you're ignoring the result of  `a.Split(',');` and then dereference the individual characters from `a`, and [`Convert.ToInt32(char)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Char_) does:

> Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the
> equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

and

> The ToInt32(Char) method returns a 32-bit signed integer that
> represents the UTF-16 encoded code unit of the value argument.

Instead use the strings after splitting:

```
string[] split = a.Split(',');
int one = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
int two = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
```

Comment: so split[0] will be referring to the first string in the array named split. when you use Convert.ToInt32(split[0]) why doesn't it treat it the same way as Convert.ToInt32(a[0]) isn't both converting a character'4'?

Comment: @TianLe It is the difference between using `char` and using `string` that is important here. `Convert.ToInt32(a[0])` calls `Convert.ToInt32(char)` which produce the unicode codepoint of the character (which is 52 for `'4'` and 51 for `'3'`), on the other hand, if you call `Convert.ToInt32(split[0])`, you call `Convert.ToInt32(string)`, and so `"4"` is then the integer 4, and `"3"` is then the integer 3.

Comment: You're a god damn genius. Apologises for the stupid question, I started learning code a few days ago.

Comment: That particular behaviour of `Convert.ToInt32(char)` catches loads of people out -- you're not alone!