# Rules for Replacing \\/ and \\r with \/ and \r respectively

Tags: c#, string

I have a big text file, containing text with mixed characters e.g.,

```
GSM \\/ HSPA \\/ LTE with 2G bands GSM 850 \\/ 900 \\/ 1800 
6.\\r\\n\\r\\nThe phone  "51": "48 MP, f\\/1.8, 26mm (wide), 1\\/2.0\", 0.8µm, PDAF\r\n8 MP, 
f\\/2.2, (ultrawide)\r\n2 MP, f\\/2.6, (macro)\r\n2 MP, f\\/2.4, "comment_status": "open",   
"image": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/lefone",
```

I have to replace the `\\/` with `\/`, `\\r` with `\r` and `\\n` with `\n`. For which I read the text file and replace these characters as given in the below code

```
string settings = File.ReadAllText(path1);
string data = File.ReadAllText(path3);
string combinedData = settings + data ;
string replacedString=combinedData.Replace(@"\\/",@"\/");
replacedString = combinedData.Replace(@"\\r", @"\r");
replacedString = combinedData.Replace(@"\\n", @"\n");
File.WriteAllText(saveFilePath, replacedString);
```

However, it does not replace properly. Only the `\\n` is replaced at some places and not at other places, The output I get is like this

```
GSM \\/ HSPA \\/ LTE with 2G bands GSM 850 \\/ 900 \\/ 1800 
6.\\r\n\\r\nThe phone  "51": "48 MP, f\\/1.8, 26mm (wide), 1\\/2.0\", 0.8µm, PDAF\r\n8 MP, 
f\\/2.2, (ultrawide)\r\n2 MP, f\\/2.6, (macro)\r\n2 MP, f\\/2.4, "comment_status": "open",   
"image": "https:\/\/www.example.com\/lefone"
```

How can I replace it correctly, what exactly are the rules for it? Please correct the code.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string.Replace (or other string modification) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working)

Comment: For the record I did not vote to close for details or clarity, I think it's pretty clear what is being asked. But I did vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you. It was very minor mistake as answered by Robson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
1: string replacedString=combinedData.Replace(@"\\/",@"\/");
2: replacedString = combinedData.Replace(@"\\r", @"\r");
3: replacedString = combinedData.Replace(@"\\n", @"\n");
```

On line 1 the code replaces text within `combinedData` and sets the result of that to `replacedString`. That's fine. Note that the contents of `combinedData` isn't changed.

On line 2 the same thing happens for `\\r`, but again we also use the original variable (`combinedData`). We're not using the variable where the previous replacement has been done (`replacedString`). That is the problem.

Line 3 has the same issue.

You want this:

```cs
1: string replacedString=combinedData.Replace(@"\\/",@"\/");
2: replacedString = replacedString.Replace(@"\\r", @"\r");
3: replacedString = replacedString.Replace(@"\\n", @"\n");
```

Alternatively, you could combine all of these operations:

```cs
1: string replacedString = combinedData
2:   .Replace(@"\\/",@"\/")
3:   .Replace(@"\\r", @"\r")
4:   .Replace(@"\\n", @"\n");
```

Comment: You are right. My mind was stuck. Thank you.