# How can i modify a string in C# by replacing text?

Tags: c#

I have a string in c#

```
  var str = "Customer.Id, Customer.User.Account.Id"
```

I want to modify this string to end up with the following; if and only if the string contains substring "Customer." like this

```
     str = "[Customer.Id], [Customer.User.Account.Id]"
```

I have tried this

```
if (query.Contains("Customer."))
{
  query.Replace("Customer.", "[Customer.");
}
```

but having trouble adding the ] at the end of Id, do i need to read until i reach the ',' ?

Any ideas how i can do this ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working) is one issue that you have. For more complicated replacements (such as this), you'll probably want to use regular expressions.

Comment: @Alexei That wasn't the only issue here.

Comment: Step1: Split string by ", " to array/list. Step 2: With LINQ .`IEnumerable.Select()` to perform string concat for "[" + value + "]" with if fulfill the condition of "Customer." substring. Step 3: Join string from array with: `String.Join(", ", array)`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar indeed... But "need focus" requires 3 votes :). OP can easily [edit] question to make clear they know how to use `Replace` (I bet they just did not properly copy-pasted they code).

Comment: @Alexei That's true.

Comment: OP. I suggest trying this regular expression: `(?<=\b| )(?<!\[)(Customer\.(.*?)(?!\])(?=,| |$))`. [Demo](https://rextester.com/AZGH42409)

Comment: If you split the string, you can use `.StartsWith("Customer.")` on each element.