# C# Replace a part of line and Write to new txt

Tags: c#

Here the code that I create to replace some value at txt file.
I want to replace the value 0 with 3 for lines which do not start with "#".

```
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Testing\Ticket_post_test.txt"))
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(@"D:\Testing\Ticket_post.txt"))
{
    string[] getFromLine = line.Split(' ');
    if (getFromLine[0].Equals("#") == false)
    {
        if (getFromLine[10].Equals("0") == true) ;
            (getFromLine[10]).Replace("0", "3");
    }
    sr.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Stuck at how to replace the 0 by 3 at line split[10] and write to a new txt file.
The txt file show below

```
*#* start time = 2021-12-03-15-14-55

*#* end time = 2021-12-03-15-15-41

*#* name = SYSTEM

bot 10 pad 11 d 4 e 6 t #0 **0** 2021-12-03-15-14-55 # - 2021-12-03-15-15-41

bot 11 pad 12 d 5 e 7 t #0 **0** 2021-12-03-15-14-55 # - 2021-12-03-15-15-41

bot 12 pad 13 d 6 e 8 t #0 **1** 2021-12-03-15-14-55 # - 2021-12-03-15-15-41
```

and more

Comment: You have a typo - a semicolon after the condition of the `if` statement. I don't know if that's present in your code or totally fixes your problem.

Comment: Your code seems to assume that splitting the `line` string allows you to manipulate the original `line` string through its individual components. In reality, you're creating a number of _new_ strings in an array. Strings are immutable, so even `getFromLine[10].Replace("0", "3")` doesn't change the value held in `getFromLine[10]`, it will simply return a _new string_ with the values replaced. You're not using that return value. You then write `line` as if you expect that to have changed, but of course you haven't (and can't) so it's still the same line as read from the original file.

Comment: `String.Replace` returns a new string, you're not assigning the result to a variable or writing it out to a new line @Yzj

Comment: It seems like you just want to assign a new value to `getFromLine[10]` when it equals `0` (i.e. `if (getFromLine[10] == "0") { getFromLine[10] = "3"; }`), and then use `string updatedLine = string.Join(" ", getFromLine);` to get the completed new string. Of course `line` won't have changed, so you'd need to write `updatedLine` to the file.

Comment: Besides what @ProgrammingLlama said, remember to check the array length before directly trying to use `[]`. Just to avoid confusion, you should remove the `*` from the sample text, which you added (probably) to highlight the values, but at first I thought they were part of the string (so your code wouldn't work, of course). You can't use bold or italics in a code block, unfortunately.

Comment: @Andrew - Yeah, the * is to highlight the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes some erroneous assumptions, which I will correct here:

1. When you split a string using `.Split` or `.Substring`, you are not creating a little window/little windows into the original string. You are producing altogether new strings.
2. When you use `.Replace`, you are creating a *new* string with the altered values, not modifying the original in-place. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-or-other-string-modification-not-working) for more info on that.

This means that:

1. Your replace is a no-op (it does nothing of any meaning).
2. Your `WriteLine` is just writing the original `line` value back to the file without your changes.

We need to both fix your replace, and create the updated string to write to the file. As we are checking the value of `getFromLine[10]`, we don't need `.Replace` at all, we can just set a new value:

```cs
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Testing\Ticket_post_test.txt"))
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"D:\Testing\Ticket_post.txt"))
    {
        string[] getFromLine = line.Split(' ');
        if (getFromLine[0] != "#" && getFromLine[10] == "0")
        {
            getFromLine[10] = "3";
        }
        sr.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", getFromLine));
    }
}
```

This isn't especially efficient, but it should get the job done. You could potentially modify it like this to avoid creating a new string when no changes have been made:

```cs
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Testing\Ticket_post_test.txt"))
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"D:\Testing\Ticket_post.txt"))
    {
        string[] getFromLine = line.Split(' ');
        if (getFromLine[0] != "#" && getFromLine[10] == "0")
        {
            getFromLine[10] = "3";
            sr.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", getFromLine));
        }
        else
        {
            sr.Write(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should probably also check the length of the array (i.e. `if (getFromLine.Length >= 11 && getFromLine[0] != "#" && getFromLine[10] == "0")` so that you don't get any `IndexOutOfRangeException` errors if you reach a line of the file that has less spaces than you expect (e.g. a blank line).

P.S. I've not tested this, so I've assumed that the rest of your logic is sound.

Comment: 3. `if (...) ;` C# doesn't care that the next line is indented, it will always run due to the extra `;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it solved my problem. I will take note for the string using. BTW it is possible to direct replace to the same txt file?

Answer (score 0):

I think this simple example will suit to your working problem.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Stack5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReadAndWriteTextFile();
        }

        private static void ReadAndWriteTextFile()
        {
            // Read text file
            // (?<string> ...) = name it with "string" name
            // ^(?!#) = select line not begin with "#"
            // (\S+\s){10} = bypass 10 group strings include a visible characters (\S) and a space (\s)
            string pattern = @"(?<one>^(?!#)(\S+\s){10})0(?<two>.+)";
            string substitution = @"${one}3${two}";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            // Change the path to your path
            List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@".\settings.txt").ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
            {
                // Check its value
                Debug.WriteLine(lines[i]);
                var match = Regex.Match(lines[i], pattern);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    string r = regex.Replace(lines[i], substitution);
                    // Check its value
                    Debug.WriteLine("Change the line {0} to: {1}",i+1,r);
                    lines[i] = r;
                }

            }
            // Write text file
            File.WriteAllLines(@".\settings.txt",lines);
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it in my local machine, hope this helps you!

Ask me if you need, good to you good to me : D

Comment: Using a `Regex` for this will probably be slower, and honestly I think the code is also much harder to understand, but still it's an interesting approach. Another performance comment: use `Count` (from `List<T>`) rather than `Count()`, which is a Linq extension method. Also note that you are overwriting the source file, unlike the original code, and that ``.\`` just means the current folder, so it's redundant.