# Function that reverses characters in (possibly nested) parentheses in the input string

Tags: c#, replace

Write a function that reverses characters in (possibly nested) parentheses in the input string.

Input strings will always be well-formed with matching ()s.

For `inputString = "(bar)`, the your text output should be solution(inputString) = `"rab"`;
For `inputString = "foo(bar)baz"`, the output should be solution(inputString) = `"foorabbaz"`;
For `inputString = "foo(bar)baz(blim)"`, the output should be solution(inputString) = `"foorabbazmilb"`;
For `inputString = "foo(bar(baz))blim"`, the output should be solution(inputString) = `"foobazrabblim"`.
Because `"foo(bar(baz))blim"` becomes `"foo(barzab)blim"` and then `"foobazrabblim"`.

I tried the code below, but every time it runs, the return value is always `inputString`. Not sure why because I am using `String.Replace`.

```
string solution(string inputString) {
    int first, last;
    string word;
    while (true) {
        if (inputString.Contains("()")) {
            first = inputString.LastIndexOf("(");
            last = inputString.IndexOf(")");
            word = inputString.Substring(first+1, last-first-1);
            inputString.Replace(inputString.Substring(first, last-first), backwardinator(word));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return inputString;
}

string backwardinator(string word) {
    string newWord = "";
    
    for (int i = word.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        newWord += word[i];
    }
    
    return newWord;
}
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [string replace does not actually replace the value in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978)

Comment: This line inputString.Contains("()") is wrong it will always result false when there are “(…)” between the parentheses

Comment: Re @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp's comment. Please note that `StringBuilder` has a `.Replace` method. Also realize that since this is very likely homework, you are unlikely to get an answer, tips and coaching yes, an answer, no

Answer (score 0):

C# Strings are immutable, which means they can’t be mutated/modified.  The method returns a new string that represents the result of the operation on the source string. In your example, you would need to assign the result of `inputSting.Replace(…)` to `inputString` much like how you’re assigning words with the result of substring the line prior.

Have you recently learned about recursion?