# string replace in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String replace not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558024/string-replace-not-working)

I have a stirng like:

```
string url = "abc=$abc";
url.Replace("$abc", "123");
```

Then what I expected it url = "abc=123". But actually, after runing above code, the result is still is "abc=$abc",  not "abc=123".

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
url = url.Replace("$abc", "123");
```

`Replace()` returns a new instance of string with the replacement operation done. It (and all other string operations) does not change the original string instance.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, this means that you create a new string instead of changing the original:

```
url = url.Replace("$abc", "123");
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, meaning it won't change in place. Try assigning the result of replace to another string variable.

```
string url = "abc=$abc";
string newUrl = url.Replace("$abc", "123");
```

Comment: i.e. string url2 = url.Replace("$abc", "123");

Answer (score 1):

try

```
url = url.Replace("$abc", "123");
```

> **[String.Replace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)**
>
> **Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
>   character or String in the current
>   string are replaced with another
>   specified Unicode character or String.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the original string, or a new string, equal to the value returned from String.Replace.  Using your example, do this:

```
string url = "abc=$abc";
url = url.Replace("$abc", "123");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
url = url.Replace("$abc", "123");
```

.Replace returns a NEW string - you must assign that back to the original string if you want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

url = url.Replace("$abc", "123");

Answer (score 0):

Replace returns a string.  So you need to change your second statement to:

```
url = url.Replace("$abc", "123");
```